Writing CR LF in text mode with MSVC
I am trying to understand the behaviour of newline characters when writing files in text mode on Windows (with MSVC). According to the Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen

it is stated that in text mode, LF (line feed) characters are translated to CR LF (carriage return + line feed) combinations on output.
Then, what happens if a thoughtful programmer tries to write the CR LF combination in text mode on Windows, e.g.,
fprintf(stream, "\r\n");

Does this result in CR CR LF, doubling the carriage return due to the translation, or is it handled differently (left as CR LR)? Is this behaviour documented anywhere in detail?

Do you have access to a Microsoft compiler? Can you test this for yourself?

@Fe2O3 The translation isn't done in the compiler - it's done in the Windows run-time library code.  And it's rather pernicious, too, as it's done at multiple levels, not only by FILE-based streams.

Only if you opened the file in text mode. In binary mode it outputs CR LF.

@AndrewHenle You misunderstand. I'm asking the OP to show some independence and answer this question for herself by compiling and running a tiny test program and observing the output. Gotta wean these kids off too much dependence on others, somehow...

The man page for fopen() describes it. Where abouts? Read the whole page, if you haven't already done so.

With the description you already found, how would any other result be possible? It doesn't state anything about skipping translation depending on preceeding characters, time of day or any other condition. If that preceeding CR would be skipped, how would you ever be able to output CR CR LF in case you really want it?

You have already found (and linked) the primary relevant documentation.  Perhaps it will help to recognize that the point is that the C programmer's view of text data is logical, not physical, including on systems where there is a larger distinction between the two than there is on Windows.  In C, the end of a line of text is represented by (only) a single newline.  When transferring data in text mode, the implementation's runtime library is responsible for translating back and forth between the relevant system text format and C's logical representation of text.

@Fe2O3 You are right. I was just lazy and stupid. I've confirmed the result by myself with a simple setup: https://github.com/tueda/test-crlf-in-text-mode/actions/runs/8818955187/job/24208995190
I was confused with a set-up that cross-compile a program with GitHub Actions + Autotools + cccl + MSVC that writes some output to the standard output, which is in text mode by default, and the output looked like CR LF is not translated to CR CR LF, but it may be an interference with the terminal enumerator and my guess was totally wrong.

@tueda I'm glad I have my antique (simple) compiler on my own computer. Scientific experiments require the investigator to strip away as many "external influences" as possible to have the "purest" chance of seeing cause-and-effect (or not seeing it.) Get ready... Somewhere here on SO, someone wrote "and MacOS uses (or used) only CR as its standard EOL character" (just to be different, I suppose.) Learning is better when its "hands-on". Have fun learning and doing your own exploring! Cheers!...

@tueda I've just voted to close (VTC) this question. Your version is only slightly different from the other question from 4 years ago (which is probably a repeat of an even older and similar question...) Sorry...

As per the man page of fopen() linked by Weather Vane in the comments:

In text mode, carriage return-line feed (CRLF) combinations are translated into single line feed (LF) characters on input, and LF characters are translated to CRLF combinations on output.

So:

In text mode, "\r\n" outputs CR CR LF.

In binary mode, "\r\n" outputs, CR LF.


